How do I configure SMS to work through email?
"Alexa how do I send SMS text messages using email? From reference.com you can send a text message from a computer through email using an SMS gateway google voice or several online SMS services."
MY QUESTION:
How do I get the SMS gateway address for a phone number, and if I configure it correctly, will the responses come to my email inbox?

Sorry, applications, protocols above the transport layer, and product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Each NE site has a [tour] and a What topics can I ask about here? page that you are expected to read before posting on the site. If you do that, then maybe you will not ask questions on the wrong site, and it will not be so useless to you.

SMS is not email, so replies are likely not to work - this depends on the gateway. Knowing which gateway to use is the age old question. (LNP made it even harder.) Pay a gateway service to figure that part out for you. Barring that, do what everyone else does... ask the person giving you the number.
